# Width of form input (using col-lg)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The width of the following form is not constrained properly when using Firefox. Instead it spans the whole screen although in Chrome it does not.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <legend class="righter">Legend</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id" class="col-lg-2 control-label">UUID</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="..."/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In JSFiddle it behaves similarly to Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/dy5KP/1/

How can I make it look like in the following picture (except for the marks) and diminish the width of the inputs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bootstrap Grid

At some point the [BootStrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) will try to collapse the fields.

There are four grid classes:

- `col-xs-*` : **Mobile**, never stacks
- `col-sm-*` : **Tablet**, stacks below **768** px
- `col-md-*` : **Laptops**, stacks below **992** px
- `col-lg-*` : **Desktop**, stacks below **1200** px

Part of the problem when looking at the code in jsFiddle is you have less real estate to look at.  When I open your code in firefox and append [/show](http://jsfiddle.net/dy5KP/1/show) to the fiddle name, I am able to get the proper behavior by making the screen wider than 1200 pixels. *See bottom of post for images*

## Solution

One solution would just be to narrow the breaking point by choosing a smaller grid column from the list above.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/sq9Xy/)

Which will look like this at any screen width:

[image: demo]

For more info you can look at [Horizontal Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) on the Bootstrap CSS page.

## Breakpoint Demo

Here's proof that your demo is working correctly by breaking at **1200px**:

**1199px**:

[image: demo1199]

**1200px**:

[image: demo1200]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this css

```
.form-group input {
width: 180px;
float: right;
margin-right: 150px
```

}

.form-group label {
    float: left
}

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy5KP/3/)

Comment: You can do this with *native* bootstrap classes, so I would recommend avoiding custom code where possible

Answer (score 0):

the best way to deal with forms in Bootstrap is to use **max-width** for the width you want , so here is what you need to do:

1- continue with your code as it but change ***col-lg-2  and  col-lg-4***

to **col-lg** only

2- in your css file ---- to the class that target the form , or make dive around your form , or simply do this:

```
.form-group input {
   display: block;
   max-width: 180px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 45px;
   margin: 5px auto;
   padding: 10px 20px;
 }
```

the **max-width:** enter the value that you want to set the width to.
the **height:** enter the value that you want the height of the field to be.

hope this will help you.